# Create sub brand account on SoftLayer API (API returning #500)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to create a Sub brand (using a self written SOAP client).

on wsdl SoftLayer_Brand#createObject asked for a parameter `templateObject` that is a `tns:SoftLayer_Brand`

Checking this complex type on xsd file I got the file type and I'm passing the following hash to request

```
longName: "Company Long Name",
name: "Company Name",
keyName: "KEY_NAME",
account: {
  address1: "123 5th Street",
  city: "City",
  companyName: "Company Name",
  country: "US",
  email: "user@mail.com",
  firstName: "First",
  lastName: "Last",
  officePhone: '1234-1234',
  postalCode: "11011",
  state: "NY"
}
```

My client is sending the request using the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <authenticate>
      <username>SL00000</username>
      <apiKey>apikeyhash</apiKey>
    </authenticate>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:createObject>
      <templateObject>
        <longName>Company Long Name</longName>
        <name>Company Name</name>
        <keyName>KEY_NAME</keyName>
        <account>
          <address1>123 5th Street</address1>
          <city>City</city>
          <companyName>Company Name - Master Account</companyName>
          <country>US</country>
          <email>user@mail.com</email>
          <firstName>First</firstName>
          <lastName>Last</lastName>
          <officePhone>1234-1234</officePhone>
          <postalCode>11011</postalCode>
          <state>NY</state>
        </account>
      </templateObject>
    </tns:createObject>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I've created Sub Brands before, but it's not working anymore, could you please point me if any parameter is missing.

On fog-softlayer we create this way https://github.com/fog/fog-softlayer/blob/master/examples/account.md#create-a-connection-to-softlayer-account-service (disclaimer: I'm one of fog softlayer maintainers)

Tried with parameters as shown on this (old) gist https://gist.github.com/underscorephil/377bd50e71ac02377008 and didn't work too.

Just would like to know if something changed or any validation is being applied to parameters.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got this figured out.

1: you are using the v3 version of the api, and while this USUALLY isn't an issue, you need to use v3.1 here.

2: In your header, you are including the SL SOAP definitions with xmlns:tns="", so you need to be using xsi:type="tns:SoftLayer_Brand"
Or you could use xmlns:v3="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/" and xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Brand"

This call worked

`curl -d @createBrand.soap.xml https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/SoftLayer_Brand`

createBrand.soap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:tns="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <authenticate>
      <username>SL1234</username>
<apiKey>kkeeyy</apiKey>
</authenticate>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
<createObject >
  <templateObject xsi:type="tns:SoftLayer_Brand">
    <longName>Company Long Name</longName>
    <name>Company Name</name>
    <keyName>KEY_NAME</keyName>
    <account>
      <address1>123 5th Street</address1>
      <city>City</city>
      <companyName>Company Name - Master Account</companyName>
      <country>US</country>
      <email>user@mail.com</email>
      <firstName>First</firstName>
      <lastName>Last</lastName>
      <officePhone>1234-1234</officePhone>
      <postalCode>11011</postalCode>
      <state>NY</state>
    </account>
  </templateObject>
    </createObject>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Seems SoftLayer WSDL is rpc/encoded (as far as I researched), and the library I was using to support SOAP operation only supports Document/literal, I added support to rpc/encoded and now things are running fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some properties were added in `createObject`:

- acknowledgementRequiredFlag and
- policyId

**Where:**

When `acknowledgementRequiredFlag` is enabled  and a new policy is added, then this policy will be shown when the user login to the portal  (User is required to see the Support Policy). Otherwise, this option can be disabled (User is NOT required to see the Support Policy).

`policyId` has two policy types:
 `”SoftLayer Indirect Support Policy” with id = 101` and `SoftLayer Standard Support Policy with id=1` (I didn't find information related to these options).

Below is a SOAP example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <SoftLayer_BrandObjectMask xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_BrandObjectMask">
         <mask xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Brand"/>
      </SoftLayer_BrandObjectMask>
      <authenticate xsi:type="v3:authenticate">
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">?</username>
         <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">?</apiKey>
      </authenticate>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v3:createObject soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
       <templateObject xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Brand">
        <keyName xsi:type="xsd:string">KEY_NAME</keyName>
        <longName xsi:type="xsd:string">Company Long Name</longName>
        <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Company Name</name>
        <account xsi:type="ns1:SoftLayer_Account">
          <address1 xsi:type="xsd:string">123 5th Street</address1>
          <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Dallas</city>
          <companyName xsi:type="xsd:string">test Company Name</companyName>
          <country xsi:type="xsd:string">US</country>
          <email xsi:type="xsd:string">user@testmail.com</email>
          <firstName xsi:type="xsd:string">FirstName</firstName>
          <lastName xsi:type="xsd:string">LastName</lastName>
          <officePhone xsi:type="xsd:string">591789611111</officePhone>
          <postalCode xsi:type="xsd:string">32124</postalCode>
          <state xsi:type="xsd:string">NY</state>
        </account>
        <supportPolicyAssignment xsi:type="ns1:SoftLayer_Policy_Brand">
          <acknowledgementRequiredFlag xsi:type="xsd:int">1</acknowledgementRequiredFlag>
          <policyId xsi:type="xsd:int">101</policyId>
        </supportPolicyAssignment>
       </templateObject>
      </v3:createObject>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: hi mcruz, sadly it didn't work, sending exactly your xml (with my data) API returned bad request. any further suggestion? thank you

Comment: in my request I just added `xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Brand"` type on template object and received a bad request too

Comment: It seems strange. I executed again the SOAP request and it works well. Currently I'm using SOAP UI, the unique difference between your Client's request and the request I sent is, that all properties listed have "xsi:type" (i.e. my case: <firstName xsi:type="xsd:string">FirstName</firstName>, client's case:<firstName>First</firstName>). Please try the client's request again adding only this section "supportPolicyAssignment" (with "acknowledgementRequiredFlag" and "policyId") avoiding "xsi:type".

Comment: hi mcruz, I tried, no success... I sent in the exactly order you shown

you SOAP request worked? mine requests (without xsi:type) I use to create dns entries, under SoftLayer_Dns_Domain... I never had a problem with the type

Comment: It works using my environment. I don't know how help you. Sorry. If I have any news I will tell you. You could open a SL ticket in order the devs can see this case. My apologies.

Comment: I did, the support agent told me to post on stack overflow... thank you very much mcruz